# to parse small document which xml parser is recomended in java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, saxparser, domparser

to parse small xml document or small xml string which xml parser is recomended in java.
I have to get attribute from a xml tag. For that I need to parse a xml string. The string is small it has 4 tags only.

Comment: Java DOM parser is good for small files.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.